# How to simplify a nested SELECT with PostgreSQL arrays?

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to speed up and simplify a SQL query against an imported OpenStreetMap database (OSM). The database is stored in a *PostgreSQL 9.2.4* server.

This OSM import features two particular tables, `planet_osm_rels` and `planet_osm_ways`. In the first table exists an relation for country boundaries, which I can extract by querying an hstore column, `tags_hstore`. The resulting `members` attribute then contains an text array giving me a bunch of information, including which ways are part of this relation. The ID of the particular ways are prefixed with `w` to indicate that it is a way ID, e.g. `w23412`. To get the actual nodes of the ways, I need to query the `planet_osm_ways` table with the IDs I obtained, minus the `w`, of course.

To summarize, I've got the following table structure:

```
   Table "public.planet_osm_rels"
   Column    |   Type   | Modifiers 
-------------+----------+-----------
 id          | bigint   | not null
 way_off     | smallint | 
 rel_off     | smallint | 
 parts       | bigint[] | 
 members     | text[]   | 
 tags        | text[]   | 
 pending     | boolean  | not null
 tags_hstore | hstore   | 
Indexes:
    "planet_osm_rels_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "planet_osm_rels_idx" btree (id) WHERE pending
    "planet_osm_rels_parts" gin (parts) WITH (fastupdate=off)
    "planet_osm_rels_tags_hstore_idx" gin (tags_hstore)

   Table "public.planet_osm_ways"
   Column    |   Type   | Modifiers 
-------------+----------+-----------
 id          | bigint   | not null
 nodes       | bigint[] | not null
 tags        | text[]   | 
 pending     | boolean  | not null
 tags_hstore | hstore   | 
Indexes:
    "planet_osm_ways_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "planet_osm_ways_idx" btree (id) WHERE pending
    "planet_osm_ways_nodes" gin (nodes) WITH (fastupdate=off)
```

I've come up with the following query:

```
SELECT  nodes
FROM    planet_osm_ways
WHERE   id IN (
      SELECT    trim(leading 'w' from unnest)::int
      FROM (
        SELECT  unnest(members)
        FROM    planet_osm_rels
        WHERE   (tags_hstore @> '"type"=>"boundary", "admin_level"=>"2", "name:en"=>"Germany"'))
      AS        unnest
      WHERE     unnest LIKE 'w%');
```

The query is, small wonder, quite slow. I know that I can (a) eliminate the `members` column by providing a link table and throw in some more indexes. However, I'd also like to optimize the query itself and at least remove one of the sub-queries, as the query plan is quite complex:

```
                                                       QUERY PLAN                                                       
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Nested Loop  (cost=299957.16..300008.23 rows=90957940 width=8)
   ->  HashAggregate  (cost=299957.15..299957.16 rows=1 width=32)
         ->  Subquery Scan on unnest  (cost=0.00..299954.76 rows=956 width=32)
               Filter: (unnest.unnest ~~ 'w%'::text)
               ->  Seq Scan on planet_osm_rels  (cost=0.00..297563.51 rows=191300 width=180)
                     Filter: ((tags)::hstore @> '"type"=>"boundary", "name:en"=>"Germany", "admin_level"=>"2"'::hstore)
   ->  Index Only Scan using planet_osm_ways_pkey on planet_osm_ways  (cost=0.01..51.06 rows=1 width=8)
         Index Cond: (id = (ltrim(unnest.unnest, 'w'::text))::integer)
(8 rows)
```

And the `EXPLAIN ANALYZE`:

```
                                                                     QUERY PLAN                                                                      
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Nested Loop  (cost=299957.16..299980.93 rows=39090200 width=1147) (actual time=18680.342..36216.571 rows=1266 loops=1)
   ->  HashAggregate  (cost=299957.15..299957.16 rows=1 width=32) (actual time=18606.686..18608.105 rows=1259 loops=1)
         ->  Subquery Scan on unnest  (cost=0.00..299954.76 rows=956 width=32) (actual time=468.391..18606.233 rows=1259 loops=1)
               Filter: (unnest.unnest ~~ 'w%'::text)
               Rows Removed by Filter: 1283
               ->  Seq Scan on planet_osm_rels  (cost=0.00..297563.51 rows=191300 width=180) (actual time=468.376..18605.288 rows=2542 loops=1)
                     Filter: ((tags)::hstore @> '"type"=>"boundary", "name:en"=>"Germany", "admin_level"=>"2"'::hstore)
                     Rows Removed by Filter: 1912651
   ->  Index Scan using planet_osm_line_pkey on planet_osm_line  (cost=0.01..23.73 rows=3 width=1155) (actual time=13.926..13.978 rows=1 loops=1259)
         Index Cond: (osm_id = (ltrim(unnest.unnest, 'w'::text))::bigint)
 Total runtime: 36217.277 ms
```

The number of rows returned isn't quite as high as to explain the long runtime:

```
 count 
-------
  1266
```

I cannot use `SELECT unnest(members) AS unnested .... WHERE unnested LIKE 'w%'` since the "unnested" part is unknown to the WHERE clause. Is there any better way to do it?

Comment: You forgot to include your version of Postgres. Also, this is just the `EXPLAIN` output. `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` would tell us more. Add the cardinality (count of rows) of the tables. And I think this is sufficiently specialized to be a better match for dba.SE. I am flagging it for migration. Leave a note if you agree.

Comment: Added the missing items. I agree to the migration.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`IN` queries with huge sets are notoriously slow. It's often faster to use a `JOIN` instead:

```
SELECT nodes
FROM   planet_osm_ways
JOIN   (
   SELECT ltrim(member, 'w')::bigint AS id
   FROM  (
      SELECT unnest(members) AS member
      FROM   planet_osm_rels
      WHERE  (tags_hstore @> '"type"=>"boundary", "admin_level"=>"2", ...')
      ) u
   WHERE member LIKE 'w%'
   ) x USING (id);
```

But that's not the most important problem here. I wonder why the GIN index `planet_osm_rels_tags_hstore_idx` is not being used. Are you selecting large enough parts of the table `planet_osm_rels` to justify a sequential scan?

Oh, and `id` is type `bigint`. So cast to `bigint` instead of `int` for less friction.

If you can extract "way IDs" and save them redundantly in a separate column `way_ids bigint[]` in your table, your query would become quite a bit simpler and faster, with one less subquery level:

```
SELECT nodes
FROM   planet_osm_ways
JOIN   (
   SELECT unnest(way_ids) AS id
   FROM   planet_osm_rels
   WHERE  (tags_hstore @> '"type"=>"boundary", "admin_level"=>"2", ...')
   ) u USING (id);
```

Comment: Wow, even after the query optimizer had done its work, your modification sped up the query by factor 7.5!

I cannot modify the tables since that would break updates, but I'll try to add an automagically updated link table via TRIGGERs.

Thanks alot!